# Solubility product constant of copper(II) bromide in water

Tags: aqueous-solution, solubility, reference-request

[One of the questions from chegg.com](https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/2-calculate-molar-solubility-cubr2-ksp-63-x-10-10--water-b-010m-cu-cn-2-solution-q36453371) mentions $K_\mathrm{sp}(\ce{CuBr2}) = 6.3\cdot 10^{-10}$, but I suspect this value might be incorrect.

Could anyone confirm or refute that $K_\mathrm{sp}$ value?

For CuBr I found Ksp values of 6.3x 10-9 and 4.0x 10-8 which is around that range. One explanation would be that the website would have wrongly attributed the Ksp of CuBr to CuBr2.

I wish Springers had the exact same paper for CuBr2, that would be just perfect. It's a solid source for the CuBr dat

As Ivan points out, wikipedia lists the solubility of CuBr2 in water as 55.7 g/100 mL (20 °C), but without listing any source. Though this value is more likely to be correct, I'm still stuck between two undocumented values that aren't close to indicating the same thing.

Buttonwood shared the link to a paper regarding CuBr which is a solid source as to it's solubility. Anything regarding CuBr2 even close to being that good would be perfect!

Comment: Sounds like nonsense to me. CuBr2 must be soluble in water fairly well, akin to CuCl2. Maybe it was _CuBr_?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copper(II)_bromide lists a solubility of $\ce{CuBr2}$ in water with 55.7 g/100 mL (20 °C), whereas CuBr is listed as "slightly soluble".

Comment: @IvanNeretin I thought so too. For CuBr I found Ksp values of 6.3x 10-9 and
 4.0x 10-8 which is around that range. Do you know the Ksp of CuBr2?

Comment: @Buttonwood The wikipedia page doesn't list any source. Though more likely to be correct, I'm still stuck between two undocumented values that aren't close to indicating the same thing.

Comment: Sigma-Aldrich sells it and they say at their website that it is soluble in water, alcohol and acetone.

Comment: I don't think this question is bad or should be closed as homework. OP demonstrated significant effort in finding related experimental data (CuBr, which is also in agreement with CRC handbook) and it's not their fault that the question on the third-party site is likely presenting false data or data for the wrong compound.

Comment: @Hans The open-access preview of e-EROS, https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/047084289X.rc207.pub2 «Copper(I) Bromide» states «Solubility: insoluble in H2O and most organic solvents; partially soluble in dimethyl sulfide.»  The entry https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/047084289X.rc206.pub2 «Copper(II) Bromide» states «Solubility: very sol water; sol acetone, ammonia, alcohol; practically insol benzene, Et2O, conc H2SO4.» Springers preview (https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF00647017) states CuBr's solubility of 0.00064 M in presence of 0.0989 M KBr at 24.8 C.

Comment: @EdV After your comment I looked at the product page, and it does list some data, but no Ksp or numerical solubility values :( This does give an indication as to what values are possible and which ones aren't though

Comment: @Buttonwood I wish Springers had the exact same paper for CuBr2, that would be just perfect. It's a solid source for the CuBr data.

Comment: @Hans Since it is soluble, there is no solubility product constant. It is just a matter of soluble, slightly soluble, highly soluble, but not a tiny solubility. For me, the hygroscopic is telling. Anyway, the actual solubility must be out there somewhere! Good luck!

Comment: @Hans Searching google "solubility CuBr2" yields an excerpt «solubility of inorganic compounds.pdf» from the 91st edition of the CRC Handbook of Chemistry and Physics, section «Aqueous solubility of inorganic compounds at various temperatures» given away by the Colorado State University.  Among the 300 compounds is CuBr2:  55.8% mass percent of solute @ 25C.  Go to the science library and browse through these thick telephone books.  Or search in Gmelin / Reaxys, if you prefer the electronic database (non-free).

Comment: @Hans Could you integrate your comment about CuBr into the question? Maybe then someone could write up an answer before the question potentially gets closed.

Comment: @KarstenTheis Done! I didn't know exactly which comment about CuBr so I integrated all my comments into the question :)